# How to install react-native-obfuscating-transformer from github

Tags: react-native, github, npm-install

`react-native-obfuscating-transformer` is no longer updated in npm repository but it is still updated in github. So I would like to know how to install it step by step from github.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the installation step in there [GitHub repo](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/react-native-obfuscating-transformer) itself.

If you are not able to install through npm and want to install directly from GitHub as an npm dependency, follow [this](https://dev.to/paddy57/how-to-fork-github-repository-and-use-as-npm-dependency-inside-a-react-native-project-2j21) article.